# If I have a vector of number and I set all the non zero value to one, can this be defined a "Normalization" process?

Tags: data-analysis

Hi all I have a vector of Numbers like this:

```
L = [[0,1,2,0],[0,0,1,5]]
```

and I have transformed it like this, so all the non zero and higher than 1 numbers has been set to 1

```
L = [[0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1]]
```

Can this operation be defined as a Normalization? if Not how can I define it?

Comment: Hi Python. I think your two-valued transformation is too crude to be called normalization. Normalization in data analysis can be done several ways, but the standard way is to normalize via the mean and standard deviation.

Comment: You *could* count this as a normalization by way of a threshold but it is going to profoundly impact all of your analysis. It is very lossy.

Comment: @CameronWilliams you gave a really exhaustive answer to my question, also by searching  "Threshold Normalization" the result is my procedure, If you have time you could answer properly so I can accept the aswer.

Comment: @Python Done. :) I'm glad I helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer since it seems to have been useful for OP:

You could count this as a normalization by way of a threshold, but it is going to profoundly impact all of your analysis. It can be very lossy.